# Python Opencv - Find black dots inside contours

Tags: python, opencv, contour, object-detection

I'm using the python wrapper for OpenCV 2.1. (I can't use any external library)

Does anyone know how can I find a black dot put inside other 2 concentric black shapes?
Now I'm using cv.FindCountours to detect the black areas, but then I don't know how to discard the 2 concentric shapes and keep only the internal dot

link to image: http://img848.imageshack.us/img848/2797/visiodrawing11.png

Comment: It is very difficult to visualize your situation without a image. Please upload your image in `imageshack.us` and provide the link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First update the OpenCV to 2.3.1

1) find all the contours after inverting image color.

2) Find their area.

3) Select the contour with minimum area or minimum perimeter.

4) That will be the center point. You can copy it to another image.